# Open files using VBA from list of file paths

Tags: vba, excel

I have list of Excel file paths in a text file (output from a VBA macro).

How can I use [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to open these files?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Something like this which will skip over invalid filenames/paths

It opens any valid workbooks stored in a textfile, `C:\temp\test.txt`, then closes them in turn

```
Sub Alistair_Cooked()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objWB As Workbook
Dim strFN As String
Dim objTF As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\test.txt")
On Error Resume Next
Do While Not objTF.AtEndOfStream
strFN = objTF.readline()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strFN)
    If wb Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print strFN
    Else
    'do something
    wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing
    End If
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```